# NVIDIA GeForce GT-710 video problems under UBUNTU 22.04.1 (now it will not go to solid black when "suspended".)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, suspend, wayland

After a badly botched automatic UPGRADE from 20.04 to 22.04.1; a fresh reinstall of 22.04.1 was acomplished in mid September, which installed the nouveau driver and XORG, since my video card is a NVIDIA GeForce GT-710.

After a few screen "suspends" I would lose keyboard and mouse control of the system. The system will track mouse movements, but will not respond to any attempts to select, highlight, or move objects. Keyboard is also unresponsive.

A "power off" reboot is necessary to restart the system. Any files not saved before the reboot are lost, otherwise the system appears to be normal.

The desktop system CPU is AMD FX-8350 (8-core) running at 3.9GHz (max); 8GB ram; two separate 1-TB HDD; 4K SAMSUNG 28" monitor; Logitech K520 and M325 wireless Keyboard & Mouse.

Note:
I use the term "suspend", but the system is NOT really suspended, power settings are set to BLACK OUT the screen after 15 minutes of inactivity. The system runs 24x7.

Upon advice from several forum postings, I installed the NVIDIA Driver 470.141.3 SERVER version, still using XORG. This minimized the wakeup problems after "suspend" but did not eliminate them. (The server version was required to be able to use nvidia-settings, and the 470 version is
the proper version for a GT-710 video card.)

---

HOWEVER,

An automatic update (Software manager) that occurred yesterday (17 October) replaced the video drivers and Display manager with "nouveau driver and Wayland"

Now the display will NOT black out totally (it dims to a dull gray), and immediately after I wake it back up, the screen jiggles for about 2-3 seconds and then settles down.

```
bill@wb4alm-07:~$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nouveau
    v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.4 driver: X: loaded: nouveau,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: nouveau resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NV106 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5 direct render: Yes
bill@wb4alm-07:~$ 


bill@wb4alm-07:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for bill: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       resources: irq:53 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
bill@wb4alm-07:~$

bill@wb4alm-07:~$ dpkg -l |grep xserver-xorg-core
ii  xserver-xorg-core  2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1  amd64  Xorg X server - core server
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsequent UBUNTU 22.04.1 updates after this problem was posted caused Wayland to be used (rather than X11), which turned out to create an unstable system.

Modifing     `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
to uncomment `#WaylandEnable=False`
and adding   `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop`

as suggested by MDeBusk to force the use of X11 has resolved the issue.

reference: [nvidia video card - X11 was working - system update changed default to wayland - now system is unstable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438634/nvidia-video-card-x11-was-working-system-update-changed-default-to-wayland)